# AJAX doesn't override already loaded scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm using a version of [jquery-ui-widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/), `1.10.3`, that works well with ajax-loaded page fragment#1 but triggers an error with page fragment#2 if fragment#2 was loaded ***after*** fragment#1.

This is strange because even if I try and override `1.10.3` with `1.8.21` when ajax-loading fragment#2 (yes I realize this is a bad hack), the code that uses the widget factory still tries to use `1.10.3` and so causes an error.

Note that this is *not* a problem during normal page load as `1.8.21` is outside of my ajax div `id="ajax_content"` and so is loaded every time.

How can I override `1.10.3` during ajax?

```
<html>
   <div id="ajax_content">
       Page fragment #1 content
      <script src="jquery-ui-widget.1.10.3.js"></script>
   </div
   <script src="jquery-ui-widget.1.8.21.js"></script>
</html>
```

VS.

```
<html>
   <div id="ajax_content">
       Page fragment #2 content
       <script src="jquery-ui-widget.1.8.21.js"></script> 
       //having this script here or not has no effect if 1.10.3 was already loaded
   </div>
   <script src="jquery-ui-widget.1.8.21.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You're sure you shouldn't just load the script once? Loading an other version doesn't magically remove anything

Comment: Because there is probably a safety check to NOT load the liabray more than once. Using two different versions of the same library is a bad idea.

Comment: I only tried to override it with `1.8.21` b/c not overriding causes the error too. Yes I realize loading 2 different versions is a bad idea but my plugins on each page don't work with the same version of jquery-ui. That's not too uncommon.

Comment: to use two versions of jquery ui, you need two versions of jquery. Include them both up front and properly manage them with $.noConflict.

Comment: @KevinB thanks. Can you provide as an answer with code how this will look? I'll upvote...

Comment: The other thing you'll have to do is properly namespace your jquery ui stylesheets since each version requires a different stylesheet.

Comment: jQuery UI is not small, including it twice is a bad idea. Ideally you should upgrade the widget that does not work. Better to do that than to find out that it does not work in IE11.

Comment: I'm not going to post it as an answer because i don't recommend anyone doing it.

Answer (score 1):

*version of jquery-ui-widget* won't have an effect. Rather the cause of your problem is that the script added to the `innerHTML` of your div `id="ajax_content"` will not execute.

A script added dynamically (which maybe received as a response of an ajax request or that dynamically added to the `innerHTML` using js or jQuery) doesn't execute. Also it is *not recommended* as per @Kevin B's comment. I worked around the same problem by either of the two solutions below:

1. **Load entire script initially**
2. **Load a new page with the script in the head tag**

---

You may disagree with the second solution here saying that the question was about the script received as a ajax response while I am suggesting you to rework your approach and use a separate page instead. This may not be appropriate to do in your scenario due to various reasons but if the only reason preventing you from doing so is that this will cause code duplication then you may explore using something like `jsp:include`.